# Custom command in Total Commander

Tags: shortcuts, total-commander

I have productivity issue with short-cut-buttons on my toolbar in Total Commander:

1. I do know how to add short-cut, which open directory in active tab (`cd c:\MyDirectory`),
2. I do know how to add short-cut, which create new tab in active window (`cm_opennewtab`)

But I do not know how to add shortcut which merge above two in one, so I can open desired directory in new tab. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out with some help on the TC official forum. Assign your keyboard shortcut to a user command which runs this:

```
%COMMANDER_EXE% "c:\your\path" /O /T /S
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm. I've already lost hope that anyone is able to solve that. I hope somebody find it useful some day.